# How to check if current page is the last within shopify collection?

Tags: shopify, liquid

I want to render some HTML element in the last page of collection, only in the last page.
I'm trying to figure out how can I check if the page is the last using liquid.

I went to Shopify documentation about paginate liquid but didn't found a solution.

Here is the pagination code of collection page -

```
  <div class="sixteen columns">
    <div class="section clearfix">
      <div class="paginate">
        {% if paginate.pages > 1 %}
          {{ paginate | default_pagination | replace: '&raquo;', '<span class="icon-right-arrow"></span>' | replace: '&laquo;', '<span class="icon-left-arrow"></span>' }}
        {% endif %}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so here is the solution I found and it works to me -

```
{% unless paginate.next.is_link %} // Check if the page is the last one
    Add HTML here
{% endunless %}
```